# Executable compiled C++ program not functioning properly

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    system("color 5");

    int Variable = 5;

    cout << " Value of variable: " << Variable << endl;
    cout << "  Value of variable x 2: " << Variable + Variable << endl;
    //Testing of string variables
    cout << endl;
    cout << "What is your name:" << flush;

    string input;
    cin >> input;

    cout << "Hello there, " << input << endl;
    //Testing of integer values below(Variable)
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the value of X: " << flush;
    int value;
    cin >> value;

    cout << "The number you entered: " << value << endl;
    cout << endl;
    //----------------------------------------------------
    cout << "Memory size of X: " << sizeof(value) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    //If statement demonstrated below
    if(value == 17) {
        cout << "Correct number selected" << endl;
    }
    if(value != 17) {
        cout << "Incorrect Number selected" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason the command prompt doesn't want to display anything after the first variable callout @ `cout << " Value of variable: " << Variable << endl;` does anyone know what the problem is? (This is when I double click the .exe file or start it form a cmd)

When I run it on CodeBlocks it runs normally with no problems at all.

Comment: "My program doesn't work."

Comment: A rule of thumb for cases like this, where Debug Mode works and Release mode doesn't, is to review all variables for initialization.  In many IDEs, the Debugger will initialize declared-only variables with some sane value.  In Release Mode, you will get whatever was in memory (maybe valid, maybe not).

Comment: By the way, you don't need `if (value != 17)` statement.  Use the `else` statement instead.  If the `==` case is not matched, execution flows to the `else` statement which is the `!=` case.